# Increase font size and space in cvitems

Tags: fontsize, awesome-cv

I am using a resume template, which uses `cvitems` and `cvsection`, which I believe is ModernCV.

I am struggling to increase size of my items.

This is the main file:

```
\documentclass[20pt, letterpaper]{awesome-cv} 
....

\input{cv-sections/projects.tex}
```

Then `projects.tex`

```
    \cvsection{Projects}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION CONTENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{cventries}

%------------------------------------------------

\cventry
{Quizzer is an \textbf{Android/web app} allowing teachers to ask questions and students answer in real time} % Job title
{Quizzer (Java, Node.js, Socket.io, MongoDB, Chart.js, jQuery, HTML/CSS)} % Organization
{} % Location
{January 2017 - May 2017} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Managed live socket connections and HTTP requests in Node.js simultaneously}
\item {Utilized custom middleware to provide secure access to user data via JSON tokens}
\item {Combined Java's Volley and Socket.io to push new data during real-time sessions}
\item{\textbf{Key Features:} Real-time distribution graph, point calculation system, absence management system, anti- cheating system, student performance statistics, archived questions directory}
\end{cvitems}
}
```

Even though I change the `documentclass` size, the overall size of the **cvitems** does not change. What can I do?

Comment: This so called "template" you are using is only for filling in content. It is not meant to be changed.  However, you got lucky because this particular "template" is supported by the author on [GitHub](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV).  It is best to file an issue there.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

`awesome-cv.cls` inherits all the options from `article.cls`.  If you [look into the source](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/blob/master/awesome-cv.cls) you will find:

```
% Inherit options of article
\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}
```

The standard `article` class only supports the sizes `10pt`, `11pt`, and `12pt`.  If you had taken a look into your log-file you would have spotted

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [20pt].
```

There is nothing you can do about that.  The only way would be to change `article` in the above snippet to `extarticle` where the available sizes are `8pt`, `9pt`, `10pt`, `11pt`, `12pt`, `14pt`, `17pt`, and `20pt`.  However, this is not a good idea either because the sizes of all the structural elements are hardcoded in `awesome-cv.cls` in units of `pt` rather than adaptive units like `ex` or `em`.

Comment: Doesn't work. Came up before. Hasn't been fixed AFAIK. Ah sorry, just read the whole answer. Yes, hardcoded. Nothing really to do here.